# LibGDX - Box2D, world, bodies and deltaTime

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Can somebody tell me how to correctly handle Box2D "deltaTime"? When I have non-Box2D objects it's sufficient to multiply `velocity` by `deltaTime` but what should I do when I use Box2D world and bodies? multiply for example `linearVelocity` by delta or `timeStep`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't multiply the *delta time* by anything for **Box2D**, just pass it in to the `World` when you do the time step.

```
// Somewhat condensed...
public class YourGameplayClass {
    private World world;
    private int velocityIterations = 4;
    private int positionIterations = 6;

    public void update() {
        world.step(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), velocityIterations, positionIteration); 
    }
}
```

**Box2D** will move your objects according to the stepped delta time and take their velocity into account for you.

Comment: I tried `world.step(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), velocityIterations, positionIteration)` and games work but only if you have 60fps. I tested game on my old smartphone and everything worked 2 times faster and game was unplayable

Comment: That problem has to do with your physics not bring decoupled from your frame rate. Gaffer on Games covers how to fix your time step in this article; http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/ . Regardless, you step a `World` by passing *a* delta to the `step` function, not by manually trying to calculate velocities.